# Java Unsafe.copyMemory java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, memory-management, unsafe

I have a problem with copyMemory from Unsafe. 
I spent 2 days in resolving it but with no result.
The code presented below always ends up with "IllegalArgumentException".
Can You help me and show where is problem ?

```
    public void testMemoryCopy() {
    class A {
        public long val = 10;
    }
    A a0 = new A();
    A a1 = new A();

    try {
        long offset = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(A.class.getField("val"));
        unsafe.copyMemory(a0, offset, a1, offset, 8);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This version of `Unsafe.copyMemory` unfortunately only works for copying to offheap memory areas (by providing `null` as destination + a absolute memory address instead of an offsett) or when copying to a **primitive** array.

When trying to specify anything else but `null` or a primitve array as third argument you will get an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.

Alternatively you could use the `Unsafe.copyMemory (long srcAddress, long destAddress, long bytes)` and directly provide the addresses (which of course is risky as the objects might have moved in the meantime).